# How to create rich tooltips and rich balloons in notification area

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, notification-area, balloon-tip

I've been wondering, whenever you call the [`ShowBalloonTip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.showballoontip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) method of the [`NotifyIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class, you get a balloon tooltip like this:

[image: Standard Baloon Tip]
**Fig1: Standard Balloon Tooltip**

Some applications and Microsoft products are able to display more than those 'simple' balloon tips.
Here are some samples:

[image: Windows Update Tip]
**Fig2: Windows Update Balloon Tooltip**

[image: Driver Installation Tip]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC295019.png))</sub>

**Fig3: Hardware Driver Installation Balloon Tooltip**

[image: USB Safely Remove]
**Fig4: Hardware Removal Tooltip (Program: USB Safely Remove)**

A good look at Figures 2, 3, and 4 reveals they aren't standard balloon tooltips!

**Fig2** has a different shape, possibly from setting the `Region` property. It also has a custom icon which is much bigger than the standard [ToolTipIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltipicon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

**Fig3** uses the standard shape (I think) but it has a custom icon which needless to say is larger than the default [ToolTipIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltipicon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) size.

**Fig4** uses a standard [ToolTipIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltipicon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) but it has a different shape.

My question is how does one create any of the 'rich' balloon tooltips that are seen in the notification area in .NET? I can handle WinAPI as well as it can produce the necessary output.

Comment: *My* good look doesn't tell me that. What's different about your look? Yes, they use large custom icons. That's been supported since Windows XP SP2. Use the [`Shell_NotifyIcon` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159.aspx) to create them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the Win32 Function [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can set the *dwInfoFlags* member of the [NOTIFYICONDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure to NIIF_USER in order to use a custom icon for the balloon tooltip.

On Windows XP Service Pack 2 and later you can use the *hIcon* member to specify a custom icon.

On Windows Vista and later the NOTIFYICONDATA structure contains the addiional member *hBalloonIcon*. You can use this member to specify a custom icon if you have set the *cbSize* member to the correct size of the extended NOTIFYICONDATA structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_TaskbarNotifier.aspx

or

www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx

Other option is to Make your own notification form balloon,
then you will have notification with flowers background and pink borders :)
BTW: that can have some functionality in it too.

**As in this example:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtA0Y.jpg
<< Image Example

Create a form as you like, Region, Controls, Etc :)
and code something like:

```
void notifyIcon_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Visible)
        {
            ShowPopup();
        }
    }

    Timer t = new Timer();
    private void ShowPopup()
    {
        Rectangle rect = Screen.GetWorkingArea(new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom));
        this.Top = rect.Bottom - this.Height;
        this.Left = rect.Right - this.Width;
        this.Visible = true;

        t.Interval = 4000;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Stop();
        Visible = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        notifyIcon.Dispose();
    }
```

BTW they all look kinda same, with different Icon size, 
and the First one could fit to the right, while all other are aligned to left...
minor shade changes Etc. :)

Comment: You really don't need to do all of that, nor do you need to use WPF. Support for this is built into Windows.

Comment: Well the windows API is capable... i didntfind a strong enogh yet easier way.  What did you have in mind?