# How to show Notification Message on Shutdown of Application WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I made application in which when user will click on close button of `MainWindow` whole application will shutdown. I want to show a Notification after closing of application. How to show a toast message as application shuts'down?
Here Code is :

```
private void Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnClosed(e);
     Application.Current.Shutdown();
 }
```

Can any one answer my question?
Feel Free to ask if my question is not clear!

Comment: Why not hide the visibility of your application, show your notification, then shutdown?

Comment: What on Earth do you want to notify the user about?  He expects your app to close, don't disappoint him.

Comment: @Shoe Thank you for comment! how to hide visibility?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create rich tooltips and rich balloons in notification area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836463/how-to-create-rich-tooltips-and-rich-balloons-in-notification-area)

Comment: I want to show a notification that application has closed! @HansPassant

Comment: @Shoe the behavior is different. What if the Application fails to shut down after the toaster? Obviously in a simple environment without side effects your solution is the easiest possible.

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi is there any other better way to do this as it is requirement of my application

Comment: @Andy it is different from what i need!

Comment: The user knows that the application shuts down because it disappears.  There is absolutely no reason to show a message saying the app has shut down.

Comment: @17of26 There is nothing about reason. it is requirement of application. can you convince your client to stop from something which he/she wants??

Answer (score 3):

Try implementing a handler for the `Window.Closing` event:

```
private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hi, I'm closing!");
}
```

This will occur *before* the `Window.Closed` event.

UPDATE >>>

@Andy and Tameen, please take a look at the [Window.Closing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) page at MSDN to see when this event *really* occurs.

> Occurs directly after Close is called, and can be handled to cancel window closure.

UPDATE 2 >>>

Your question does *not* state that you want to cancel the `Close` event. However, that is *exactly* what the `Closing` event is for:

```
private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hi, I'm closing!");
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Removed my downvote since the incorrect statement has been removed.  Note that when I originally downvoated this text was included "This will occur `after` the Window.Close `event`."  Technically there is no Close event, only Closing and Closed. Note that `close event` and `close method` are very different things, which was why I downvoted, since I assumed the text meant `Closed event`, not `Close method`.

Answer (score 1):

Your application shutdowns by default when the mainwindow closes. Allow the button to signal the window close and handle the toast in the `Closed` event.

```
<Window ... Closed="Window_Closed" />

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Cya");
}
```